# How to take multiple output file name as a command line argument in lexical analyzer FLEX?

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I want to take three file name as a command line argument for lexical analyzer FLEX , among these three one for input file and remaining two for output file. It is easy to take one input file name and another output file name but I don't know how should I store multiple output file name in "yyout" .Please help me to solve it out.

```
FILE *fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE *output1 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
if(fin==NULL){
       printf("Cannot open specified file\n");
       return 0;
   }
   

yyin = fin;
yyout =output1;
```

It is okay for one input file and output file but what if I want something like---

```
FILE *fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE *output1 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
FILE *output2= fopen(argv[3], "w");
if(fin==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open specified file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    

yyin = fin;
yyout =output1;
```

How I store both output1 and output2 in yyout?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What output do you want to end up in those files? Output generated by the default rule (i.e. when no rule matches your input)? Or output generated by your own code in actions? In the latter case, just write to whatever files you want and don't worry about `yyout`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write to two files simultaneously in C, as far as I know. However, an alternative would be to make a copy of the first file after writing it.

```
FILE *fin=fopen(argv[1],"r");
FILE *output1 = fopen(argv[2], "w");
FILE *output2= fopen(argv[3], "w");
if(fin==NULL){
        printf("Cannot open specified file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
// call the lexer with the first output file
yyin = fin;
yyout =output1;
yylex();

// reopen output file for input
fclose(output1);
output1 = fopen(argv[2]), "r");

// copy to the second file
while ((ch = fgetc(output1)) != EOF)
    fputc(ch, output2);
```

Extracted from [C program to copy a file](https://www.programmingsimplified.com/c-program-copy-file),